# Can't append nodes to empty div

Tags: javascript, html, dom

```
<div id = "first"></div>
<div id = "second"></div>
<div id = "third"></div>
```

Trying to dynamically append to these divs within a javascript function

```
if (condition??) variable = "first"
else if (condition) variable = "second"
else variable = "third"

let div = document.getElementById(variable);
```

Variable above could be first, second, or third depending on some condition.

```
div.appendChild(img)  
div.appendChild(text)
```

However since div ends up being null I wont be able to append anything to it cuz of the following error.

```
Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null.
```

So any idea how to go around this?

Edit: Added the actual code snip below

```
// my html
<div id = "list" class = "center"> Listing <br><br>
    <div id = "first"></div>
    <div id = "second"></div>
    <div id = "third"></div>
</div>

//my js
$.ajax({
        async: true,
        type: 'GET',                
        url: "rankings/" + boss + ".txt",
        boss : boss,
        success: function(sData){
            let temp = this.boss
            let div = document.getElementById(temp);
            //console.log(temp) logs "first" on the console
            let img = document.createElement("img");    
            let text = document.createElement('td1');
            img.src = "images/" + temp + ".jpg";
            img.alt = temp
            div.appendChild(img)  
            div.appendChild(text)
```

Edit 2: Image of code exection

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cjkZS.jpg

Comment: can you show us how are to assigning value to "variable" in "let div = document.getElementById(variable);"

Comment: exactly like below that! I use appendChild to that empty div but that doesnt work out.

Comment: I mean what is "variable"? Show that code as well.

Comment: Ah, variable gets set to "first", "second" or "third" depending on some if statements.
So that line is actually let div = document.getElementById("first")

Comment: The `appendChild` function depends on the children being [nodes](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_appendchild.asp). Are you creating nodes, or just trying to append an html string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks correct! However, I think the problem is, you are loading the Javascript before the DOM is being rendered (Eg. you are loading the script in `<head>`). So javascript is not able to find the divs..

```js
var variable= "second";
var boss = "boss_baby";
let div = document.getElementById(variable);
console.log(variable) //logs "first" on the console
let img = document.createElement("img");    
let text = document.createElement('td1');
img.src = "images/" + boss + ".jpg";
img.alt = boss
div.appendChild(img)  
div.appendChild(text)
```

```css
#first, #second, #third {
display:block;
border: 1px solid blue;
height: 50px;
width: 200px;
margin : 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id = "list" class = "center"> Listing <br><br>
    <div id = "first"></div>
    <div id = "second"></div>
    <div id = "third"></div>
</div>
```

To solve this issue you can either load the `<script>` right before the body tag ends `</body>`

or add all your script in [onload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload) methods

```
window.onload = function() {
// all your JS code goes here
}
```

OR

```
document.onload = function() {
// all your JS code goes here
}
```

**After question EDIT:**

Your code looks correct! However, Now i suspect the element you are trying to access might have been removed by the time you get your response from ajax.

Comment: I hope this work. I had the same issue when i started learning Javascript.

Comment: I've actually considered this but this wasnt the issue either.
Another hint I can add is that the part I named as "my js" is actually part of an async function. 
I wonder if that could be the reason.

Comment: Only possible explanation as in why you get `null` is, that the element is not yet in the DOM when the javascript line executes. 
Could you please update the code snippet with the `async` implementation as well? Will try with `async` functions on my end too

Comment: Tried with `async` function 
`appendElements().then(status => {
console.log(status); // Status is returned from your snippet block as appendElements()
})` . Works as expected. 

I don't think its related to `aysnc`

Comment: I dont think it is the async though.
I have a breakpoint on the line 
let div = document.getElementById(variable);
and variable seems about right but div gets assigned to nothing.

Comment: Also added an image to further explain code execution.
I believe the html is corrupted somehow at somepoint ??

Comment: I ran your js code in the same html file right before `</body>` and it works! Please do give it a try.

Comment: "html is corrupted" ? You mean DOM is updated/removed. Yeah! its possible in your actual implementation. But as per the code snippet you shared, i am pretty sure, its all about when and how you link the js to the html. Because i have ran all your code snippets on my end and they work perfectly.

Comment: Yeah thanks for all the help. I found the problem. What I did is I had a onclick function for a parent tag to the div we are talking about. So when that onclick event occurs all the "first" "second" id'd tags ended up being deleted. Which is why we cant reach them after some time in the execution.

Comment: There you go. :) Glad i could be of any help. Please do upvote or choose an answer when you get a solution.
Welcome to stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

Try this [Code Pen Example](https://codepen.io/Sandip_01/pen/BmBYwO) . I think your problem is with the "variable" and how your assigning value to it.

```
  <div id = "first" style="border:1px red solid"></div>
    <div id = "second" style="border:blue"></div>
<div id = "third" style="border:green"></div>
    <script>
//try changing the value of condtion
var condition=3;
var variable="";
var img = document.createElement("img");   
//var text = document.createElement('td1');
img.src = "https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/fjords.jpg";
img.alt = "boss"
//div.appendChild(img) 

if (condition==1) variable = "first"
else if (condition==2) variable = "second"
else variable = "third"
console.log(img)
document.getElementById(variable).appendChild(img);
    <script>
```

Comment: @Thasd Try this [link] (https://codepen.io/Sandip_01/pen/BmBYwO). What is "td1" in your above code??